# How to implement LDA with collapsed Gibbs sampling with R-JAGS?

Tags: r, jags

I am trying to implement LDA model with JAGS:

```
model {

    for (i in 1:M) {
      theta[i,1:K] ~ ddirch(alpha)
    }


    for (i in 1:K) {
      phi[i,1:V] ~ ddirch(beta)
    }


    for (i in 1:W) {
      z[i] ~ dcat(theta[D[i],])
      w[i] ~ dcat(phi[z[i],])
    }
   }
```

The program has crashed as Gibbs sampling for LDA is too heavy. Now I'd like to implement it with `collapsed Gibbs sampling`. Do you know how to sample in that way with JAGS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question hasn't received enough attention because it's poorly worded, it's unclear what your error is, documentation to your jargon is not provided, and it's unclear what your expected solution is. Adding a bounty won't help this. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Alex sorry indeed I have add some parameters in LDA, and I think it's much worse to put all of the code here as the problem will be more unclear. And what I want just the way to implement collapsed Gibbs sampling with JAGS. Thanks

Comment: I'm not positive of this, but I'm pretty sure that the only way to implement collapsed sampling in JAGS is to integrate the parameter you want to collapse out of the likelihood yourself.  i.e. reparamatrize the likelihood to collapse.

Comment: What error did JAGS throw when it crashed?  It seems plausible to me that the problem here is something other than "the sampling is too heavy" whatever that means.

Comment: @JacobSocolar is correct. You would need to integrate a parameter out for collapsed Gibbs in JAGS, and I am uncertain that you can do this with LDA models (but I have little experience with them).

Comment: Equation 2 here gives the collapsed likelihood, but looks like a headache to implement in JAGS:
http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v36/qiu14.pdf